# Find-Module -Name GetStuff | Install-Module succeedes, but Get-Command -Module GetStuff fails

Tags: powershell

The module appears to be installed, but cannot find or use commands. Get-Command returns nothing.

Have you experienced this? What is the cause of this situation?

```
PS C:\> Find-Module -Name GetStuff | Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser
PS C:\> Get-Command -Module GetStuff
```

Comment: Does `Import-Module GetStuff` work? I can't remember the exact mechanics of module auto-loading, but I suspect PowerShell caches module metadata on startup, if you exit and re-launch PowerShell it'll likely work

Answer (score 0):

User running PowerShell 5.1.17134.858 fails

User running PowerShell 5.1.17763.1490 succeeds

Case closed until user tests newer version.